# Sum values with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a few dynamically generated rows of divs that contain divs. Each of those divs contain a value inside a custom container. The structure looks something like this:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="block">
        <div data-a="2"></div>
        <div data-b="3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div data-a="1"></div>
        <div data-b="3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div data-a="5"></div>
        <div data-b="2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="block">
        <div data-a="2"></div>
        <div data-b="3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div data-a="1"></div>
        <div data-b="3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div data-a="5"></div>
        <div data-b="2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to calculate totals for data-a and data-b within each .mainDiv

I've tried the loops but I'm not sure whether I'm getting the values from attributes correctly.

```
sumTotals = function(selector) {
      var sum = 0;
      $(selector).each(function() {
          sum += 1*($(this).text());
      });
      return sum;
}

$(".mainDiv").each(function(){
        var views = sumTotals($(this).attr("data-a"));
        var ptcps = sumTotals($(this).attr("data-b"));
        ...
});
```

I think I'm getting close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you were close, but here take a look at this code :

```
sumTotals = function(context, selector) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('[data-'+selector+']', context).each(function() {
        sum += 1*($(this).data(selector));
    });
    return sum;
}

$(".mainDiv").each(function(){
    var views = sumTotals(this, "a");
    var ptcps = sumTotals(this, "b");
    console.log(views, ptcps)
});
```

You see, in this code, you passing the context and the data-* you want to get.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/5T8bs/

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you pass into that function has to be an array of items (or a selector that produces an array of items). `.attr` doesn't return an array, it returns the attribute's value for the *first* element in the collection, so that's all your passing in: A single value.

That single item still isn't correct though, because `this` is the `.mainDiv`, *not* the sub element that has a `data-a` attribute, it's the `.mainDiv`.  Within each `.mainDiv`, you need to find all the elements that have the attribute you're after, then map them to the value of that attribute, and sum the resulting set of values:

```
$(".mainDiv").each(function(){
    var views = sumTotals($(this).find('div[data-a]').map(function () {
      return $(this).data('a');
    });

    var ptcps = sumTotals($(this).find('div[data-b]').map(function () {
      return $(this).data('b');
    });
});
```

... *or* just sum the arrays in place, which is probably easier.

Comment: There is only **one** element with `class="mainDiv"` in sample data... Probably need to loop through `class="block"` instead

Comment: @poncha No, read it again, there are several `.mainDivs` and the question clearly states "I need to calculate totals for data-a and data-b within each .mainDiv".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works too - though admittedly, I didn't seperate out a|b. I assumed you want a combined total. Others have nice solutions for the seperation: ptcps and views

```
var ttlNum = 0;
var totals = jQuery('.mainDiv').find('div').map(function(){
     return jQuery(this).data('a') || jQuery(this).data('b');
}).each(function(i,v){
   ttlNum += v;
})
```